# Using a specific font in web development

Tags: html, fonts

I downloaded the Franchise Bold Font. I know how to use it in my code, but where do I put the font files in my webserver root so that they get found and used?

the URL is: http://www.derekweathersbee.com/franchise/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a font on a web page it needs to be a WebFont - you can't just put a TTF file onto a webserver.

Font Squirrel offer a service to create/convert WebFonts - there's a fair bit of info on how it works there and a Google for webfonts will bring up a tonne more.

Obviously you need to rights to do convert and use the font - the font you're using appears to be free but if I were you I'd credit the creator/throw them a link somewhere!!

Comment: oh, yes, I plan to give credit. How do I use the WebFont once I have it created? Where does it go and how do I reference it?

Comment: Quick tip: Webfont support is good but there are still some browsers which don't support it well and you need to do things slightly differently for some browsers.  Also, beware webfonts which scale differently to the defaults (many of the free Google ones do this) as your website layout will go horribly wrong on browsers where the webfont isn't supported (test your website with a 'broken' webfont like to see this)